# Is there a way to set a default value for an array of objects in a yaml template (Azure Pipelines)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a yaml template that contains parameters like below. In the array / list I want to be able to set the default value for one of the properties (the object has 3). The reason being is I have some if statements that check these properties and I want them to run regardless of whether or not the property is set in the yaml that uses the template (the third property was added later and I don't want to have to update every repo that uses this template).

Is this something that can be done in the parameter setup?

Notes: Using the below example if the property WebProject is not used I would like everything to go through the template as if it was set to false. I know there is some duplication where I check the property and copy files / publish the artifacts but at the moment I want to get it working and make it more efficient afterwards.

yaml template

```
parameters:
- name: ArtifactPublish
  type: boolean
  default: false
- name: Solution
  type: string
  default: '**/*.sln'
- name: Artifacts
  type: object
  default: []
jobs:
- job: Build
  displayName: 'Build, Pack, and Publish'
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  variables:
    solution: ${{ parameters.Solution }}
    buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
    buildConfiguration: 'Release'

  - task: VSBuild@1
    displayName: 'Build Solution'
    inputs:
      solution: '$(solution)'
      msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"'
      platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
      configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

  - ${{ if eq(parameters.ArtifactPublish, true) }}:
    - ${{ each artifact in parameters.Artifacts }}:
      - ${{ if eq(artifact.WebProject, false) }}:
        - task: CopyFiles@2
          displayName: 'Copy .artifactignore: ${{ artifact.ArtifactPath }}'
          inputs:
            SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
            Contents: '.artifactignore'
            TargetFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/${{ artifact.ArtifactPath }}'

        - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
          displayName: 'Publish Artifact: ${{ artifact.ArtifactName }}'
          inputs:
            targetPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/${{ artifact.ArtifactPath }}'
            artifactName: '${{ artifact.ArtifactName }}'

      - ${{ if eq(artifact.WebProject, true) }}:
        - task: CopyFiles@2
          displayName: '${{ artifact.ArtifactPath }}*'
          inputs:
            SourceFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
            Contents: '${{ artifact.ArtifactPath }}*'
            TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/${{ artifact.ArtifactPath }}'
            
        - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
          displayName: 'Publish Artifact: ${{ artifact.ArtifactName }} (WEB)'
          inputs:
            targetPath: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/${{ artifact.ArtifactPath }}
            artifactName: '${{ artifact.ArtifactName }}'
```

Example yaml that uses the template:

```
trigger:
  - release
  - development
  - master
  - feature/*
  - task/*

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      name: Project/RepoName
      type: git
      ref: refs/heads/release
  
jobs:
- template: Templates/example.yml@templates
  parameters:
    ArtifactPublish: true
    Artifacts:
    - ArtifactPath: 'example/path'
      ArtifactName: 'exampleName'
    - ArtifactPath: 'example/path'
      ArtifactName: 'exampleName'
      WebProject: true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid setting the default value for one of the properties cannot be done in the parameters setup.

But you can use the [coalesce expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#coalesce) to check if the `WebProject` parameter is set or not:

> - Evaluates the parameters in order, and returns the value that does not equal null or empty-string.
>   Min parameters:
> - Max parameters: N
> - Example: coalesce(variables.couldBeNull, variables.couldAlsoBeNull, 'literal so it always works')

So you can use the expression  `coalesce(artifact.WebProject, false)` in your template yaml as below:

```
- ${{ if eq(parameters.ArtifactPublish, true) }}:
  - ${{ each artifact in parameters.Artifacts }}:
    - ${{ if eq(coalesce(artifact.WebProject, false),false) }}:
```

With this expression `- ${{ if eq(coalesce(artifact.WebProject, false),false) }}`, No matter whether parameter `WebProject` is set to false or not used, this expression will always be true.

Comment: Thanks, bummer about not being able to set defaults in the parameters like I wanted but this gets me where I need to be.